# Halo Sport For Instrument Practice

Tags: guitar, practice

I am going to integrate Halo Sport into my regular guitar practice sessions. Has anybody tried this kind of technology with their musical workout. I saw the video by Mario Marzo, which is not produced by Halo Neuro and was impressed. After reading up on tDCS, I think this may be the way to go for a lot of guitar and challenges - muscle memory (fretting and strumming) and motor skill (playing while singing especially).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the Mario Marzo video isn't a deliberate fake, it is still worthless as a demonstration that the Halo Neuro has any effect, for one simple reason.

*Marzo knew when he was wearing the Halo, and when he wasn't.* Since he had already decided the Halo was worth buying, he got the result he expected to get.

Of course this is a fundamental problem with many psychological experiments on humans, since the humans *know that they are being experimented on.* Some people even go so far as to argue that it's logically impossible for "experimental human psychology" to ever be "scientific", for that reason.

A *fairer* trial would have been to use two identical-looking headsets, without Mario knowing which was real and which was a dummy until *after* he had compared the speed of learning the two pieces.

It seems that *no* peer-reviewed, properly conducted trials of the Halo device have been published. But hey, if you want to spend your money on one, go for it. It probably won't make you any *worse* as a guitarist - unless it irreversibly fries your brain, of course!

Comment: This may seem arbitrary but I notice that the term *neuropriming* is not a science term, but is a marketing term only associated with Halo products. It's been my experience that products "based on science" that use actual scientific concepts in their marketing are less often snake oil than products that use psuedoscientific terms in their marketing.

Comment: This article indicates positive results of transcranial electrical stimulation during **learning** (not muscle training): https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4064117/ The only information I can find online about whether brain stimulation affects physical training seems to all lead back to Halo. The closest I could find is this paper is about how neural stimulation might help stroke victims regain motor function: https://www.rehabmedicine.umn.edu/research/research-studies/participate-research/brain-stimulation-hand-training

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Even with a fairer trial, the user of a placebo headset would still not feel any stimulus and know they have the placebo headset. I am going to go ahead and give it a try... will see if I notice any difference in a couple weeks then post back here. But still won't know if it is the Halo or because I know that I am using the Halo...

Comment: Horvath, Jared; Forte, Jason; Carter, Olivia (2015). "Quantitative Review Finds No Evidence of Cognitive Effects in Healthy Populations From Single-session Transcranial Direct Current Stimulation (tDCS)". Brain Stimulation. 8: 535–50.

Comment: I am now a week into using it and have the same impression as the cellist in the video. Not as hyped and convinced as the pianist. Something is different and positive, but cannot quite describe it. I am using the same practice regimen as usual. I practice in the morning with mechanics, rhythm, and new material for about an hour at the home studio. Then work refinement and existing works for about an hour in the afternoon at an external studio. The difference in retention is noticeable, but not so great that I would run out and buy the Halo T-shirt and logo underwear....lol